# On $\mathbb{R}$ with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, is $e^x$ measuable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Well for any $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ we want that the set $S = \{x \mid f(x) > \lambda\}$ is in the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, $B$, i.e. the algebra generated by the intervals.

Well firstly, for any value of $\lambda \le 0$ we will have that $f(x) > \lambda$ for all $x$. So $S$ in this case is $\mathbb{R}$ which is in $B$.

Then, if we consider any $\lambda > 0$ we will have that $S = \{x \mid e^x> \lambda\} = \{x \mid x > ln \lambda\} = (ln \lambda, \infty)$

$S$ is an interval so it is $B$.

Does this look ok?

Comment: The argument looks good to me.

Comment: Yes. In fact, every continuous function is measurable because the inverse image of open sets is open (and hence a Borel set)

Comment: something to think about: Does your argument show that any function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ which is strictly monotone is Borel measurable?

Comment: @Tom Yes I would think so intuitively as the set $S$ will always equal $\emptyset, \mathbb{R}$ or some interval on $\mathbb{R}$?